# Compile time type check when adding element elements to list

Tags: scala, types

Is it possible to implement it at compile time using Scala?

Use case:

- API user tries to build a list of `Thing`s.
- Once user adds subclass of `ComplexThing`,  he is not allowed to add anything else

It's easy to check in runtime, and are there any solutions to implement it at compile time?
The goal is to make IDE to highlight compile error.

```
trait Thing

trait SimpleThing extends Thing

trait ComplexThing extends Thing

sealed case class DummySimpleThing() extends SimpleThing

sealed case class InstanceOfComplexThing() extends ComplexThing

class ThingRepository {
  private val buffer = new ListBuffer[Thing]()

  def addThing(thing: Thing): ThingRepository = {
    buffer += thing
    this
  }
}

object TestThingRepository {

  def testAddThings() = {
    new ThingRepository()
      .addThing(DummySimpleThing())
      .addThing(DummySimpleThing()) // it's ok to add SimpleThing after SimpleThing
      .addThing(InstanceOfComplexThing()) // it's ok to add ComplexThing after SimpleThing

      .addThing(DummySimpleThing()) // Not allowed to add anything after ComplexThing, how can I get compile time error here?
      .addThing(InstanceOfComplexThing()) // Not allowed anything after ComplexThing, how can I get compile time error here?
  }
}
```

Comment: typically you would only have `sealed`  traits and if anything make the case classes `final`. 

It is explained well here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31133245/5725677

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with a mutable repository because you can't change the signature of a class once it is defined.

It would be possible to do this if `addThing` returned a new repository, because adding `ComplexThing` could return a repository without an `addThing` method while adding `SimpleThing` returns a repository with an `addThing` method.

```
case class StaticThingRepository(buffer: List[Thing])

class ThingRepository private(buffer: List[Thing]) {  
  def addThing(thing: Thing): ThingRepository =
    new ThingRepository(buffer :+ thing)

  def addThing(thing: ComplexThing): StaticThingRepository =
    StaticThingRepository(buffer :+ thing)
}

object ThingRepository {
  def apply() = new ThingRepository(Nil)
}
```